# Incorrect data is being pushed into stack implemented using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I have implemented stack using pointers. I have been trying to generalize it for use with arbitrary data type. I have tried but cannot figure out the reason incorrect data is being pushed onto the stack.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum action {START, PUSH, POP, TOP, LENGTH, QUIT, END};
enum status {SUCCESS, FAILURE};

typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *lower;
} stack_node;

typedef struct stack {
    size_t elem_size;
    size_t stack_size;
    stack_node *top;
} stack_struct;

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = START;
    do {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d See the length of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, LENGTH, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (!(START < choice && choice < END));
    return (enum action) choice;
}

enum status stack_create(stack_struct **stack, size_t elem_size)
{
    (**stack).elem_size = elem_size;
    (**stack).stack_size = 0;
    (**stack).top = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status push(stack_struct **stack, void *data)
{
    stack_node *node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    node->data = malloc(sizeof((**stack).elem_size));
    if (node->data == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    memcpy(node->data, data, (**stack).elem_size);

    if ((**stack).top == NULL) {
        node->lower = NULL;
    } else {
        node->lower = (**stack).top;
    }
    (**stack).top = node;
    (**stack).stack_size += 1;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status pop(stack_struct *stack, void *data)
{
    if (stack->top == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    stack_node *node = stack->top;
    memcpy(data, node->data, stack->elem_size);
    stack->top = node->lower;

    free(node->data);
    free(node);

    stack->stack_size -= 1;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status peek(stack_struct *stack, void *data)
{
    if (stack->top == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    memcpy(data, stack->top->data, stack->elem_size);
    return SUCCESS;
}

void stack_delete(stack_struct *stack)
{
    while (stack->top != NULL)
    {
        stack_node *node = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->lower;
        free(node->data);
        free(node);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum action choice;
    stack_struct *stack = malloc(sizeof(stack_struct));
    if (stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    stack_create(&stack, sizeof(int));

    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT) {
        clear_screen();
        int data;
        switch (choice) {

            case PUSH:
                printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                if (push(&stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("%d pushed onto the stack", (int)stack->top->data);
                } else {
                    printf("Not enough memory\n");
                }
                break;

            case POP:
                if (pop(stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("The data is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Stack underflow\n");
                }
                break;

            case TOP:
                if (peek(stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Nothing in the stack\n");
                }
                break;

            case LENGTH:
                printf("Length is %d\n", stack->stack_size);
                break;

            default:
                assert(!"You should not have reached this.\n");

        }
        stack_delete(stack);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

I push 234 and get a garbage value.

**Update 1**

I have a working copy of stack using pointers. It isn't for arbitrary data types but only for `int`. It [can be viewed on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29213/review-implementation-of-stack-by-using-pointers-in-c) where I got the idea to make it for arbitrary data.

**Update 2**

After p0w pointed out that the `printf` in the `main` was incorrect I correct that. I also changed the `pop`, `peek` and `stack_delete` function so that pointer to pointer to `struct` is passed.

`printf` shows that correct data is being passed but `pop` and `peek` don't think so.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum action {START, PUSH, POP, TOP, LENGTH, QUIT, END};
enum status {SUCCESS, FAILURE};

typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *lower;
} stack_node;

typedef struct stack {
    size_t elem_size;
    size_t stack_size;
    stack_node *top;
} stack_struct;

void clear_screen(void)
{
    system("cls");
}

static enum action get_user_action(void)
{
    int choice = START;
    do {
        clear_screen();
        printf("%d Push data\n"
               "%d Pop Data\n"
               "%d See the top of the stack\n"
               "%d See the length of the stack\n"
               "%d Exit\n\n"
               "Enter your choice -> ", PUSH, POP, TOP, LENGTH, QUIT);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } while (!(START < choice && choice < END));
    return (enum action) choice;
}

enum status stack_create(stack_struct **stack, size_t elem_size)
{
    (**stack).elem_size = elem_size;
    (**stack).stack_size = 0;
    (**stack).top = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status push(stack_struct **stack, void *data)
{
    stack_node *node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    node->data = malloc(sizeof((**stack).elem_size));
    if (node->data == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    memcpy(node->data, data, (**stack).elem_size);

    if ((**stack).top == NULL) {
        node->lower = NULL;
    } else {
        node->lower = (**stack).top;
    }
    (**stack).top = node;
    (**stack).stack_size += 1;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status pop(stack_struct **stack, void *data)
{
    if ((**stack).top == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    stack_node *node = (**stack).top;
    memcpy(data, node->data, (**stack).elem_size);
    (**stack).top = node->lower;
    node->lower = NULL;

    free(node->data);
    free(node);

    (**stack).stack_size -= 1;
    return SUCCESS;
}

enum status peek(stack_struct **stack, void *data)
{
    if ((**stack).top == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    memcpy(data, (**stack).top->data, (**stack).elem_size);
    return SUCCESS;
}

void stack_delete(stack_struct **stack)
{
    while ((**stack).top != NULL)
    {
        stack_node *node = (**stack).top;
        (**stack).top = (**stack).top->lower;
        free(node->data);
        free(node);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum action choice;
    stack_struct *stack = malloc(sizeof(stack_struct));
    if (stack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    stack_create(&stack, sizeof(int));

    while ((choice = get_user_action()) != QUIT) {
        clear_screen();
        int data;
        switch (choice) {

            case PUSH:
                printf("Enter data to be pushed -> ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                if (push(&stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("%d pushed onto the stack\n", *(int *)stack->top->data);
                    printf("%u is top of stack", stack->top);
                } else {
                    printf("Not enough memory\n");
                }
                break;

            case POP:
                if (pop(&stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("The data is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Stack underflow\n");
                }
                break;

            case TOP:
                if (peek(&stack, &data) == SUCCESS){
                    printf("The data at top is %d\n", data);
                } else {
                    printf("Nothing in the stack\n");
                }
                break;

            case LENGTH:
                printf("Length is %d\n", stack->stack_size);
                break;

            default:
                assert(!"You should not have reached this.\n");

        }
        stack_delete(&stack);
        getchar();
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the `delete_stack` funciton outside the loop.

Comment: Why is this code crashing on `VS2010` but not on `GCC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your struture `data` is `void *` so fix `printf`

`printf("%d pushed onto the stack", *(int *)stack->top->data);`

However, there seems to be other problems too for other stack operations.

Also if you're planning for making it as a generic Stack, why `%d` in `printf` ?

This you might need to re-visit.

Comment: This `%d` was used just for testing purpose. After this correction the correct data is being shown by the `printf` but the `pop` and `peek` are still not considering that it has been placed. I'll add updated code to the question.

Comment: @AseemBansal are you new on SO, doesn't look like, if you fix this, theres' no question at all. Please use another post of some new issues ?

Comment: No arguments against that. I'll ask another one. This time with a proper heading.

Comment: There is crash in `stack_delete` function  while doing `free(node)`

Comment: @UchiaItachi I didn't get that far. `pop` isn't recognizing that I pushed something

Comment: Shouldn't `delete_stack`  be outside the while loop?

Comment: @UchiaItachi And this should be an answer so make it one. It solved the whole problem. Thanks.

Comment: But there is still a crash in the `pop` function in `free(node)` i am unable to figure out why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34790/discussion-between-aseem-bansal-and-uchia-itachi)

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to the points mentioned by P0W and me, there is bug in your code which is leading to a crash on `VS2010` but not in `GCC`.

While creating the stack_node object in `push` function dynamically you're passing the `sizeof(node)` where `node` is a pointer of `stack_node` instead you should've passed `sizeof(stack_node)`.

The amount of memory `malloc` allocates in both the cases is different. 
In the first one you get `4 bytes`(beacuse of size of pointer) and in the second one you get `8 bytes` (because of size of stack_node).

In this case you don't get to access the second member of `stack_node` object which is         `struct node *lower`. Also, this might need to undefined behavior as you're accessing the memory which is not allocated.

Finally at the statement `free(node)` it crashes.

I don't know the exact reason as to why this is happening and also i don't know how `free` works behind the scenes.

I would like to know the reason in this case.

Comment: I had no idea that this bug was present. I have no idea as to why it is giving an error in `VS2010` but working in `gcc`. You can ask a question on stackoverflow with a link to this code and ask why. I did that for a question whose explanation I didn't understand.

Comment: If you do ask a question then please post a comment with the link. I'm also interested how that worked in `gcc` when it is actually wrong.